# How To Run CMD Commands In Vb6 As Administrator

Tags: vb6

How To Run CMD Commands In VB6 As Admin.

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="admin" key="admin"
```

HOW CAN I RUN THIS COMMAND WITH ADMIN RIGHTS USING CMD.

```
Dim sYourCommand As String

sYourCommand = "netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="admin" key="admin""

Shell "cmd /c " & sYourCommand, vbMaximizedFocus
```

HOW CAN I RUN ABOVE COMMAND AS ADMIN privileges.

Comment: ShellExecute with "runas" should meet your requirement: ShellExecute 0, "runas", "c:\folder\yourapp.exe", Command & "/admin", vbNullString, SW_SHOWNORMAL

Comment: If your VB6 programming is running as admin access, any process that is started from it will also run with admin access.  You can have your apps run as admin rights by right clicking on the EXE and going into the Compatibility tab and checking the option to run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Declarations:

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
```

Code:

```
ShellExecute 0, "runas", "c:\folder\yourapp.exe", Parameter, vbNullString, SW_SHOWNORMAL
```

Source: *https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?608723-RESOLVED-Run-as-administrator-automatically*

Answer (score -2):

Shell "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c" & sYourCommand, vbMaximized